# ExactTareget Crypto HMACSHA256

Tags: marketing-cloud

**Situation**

I want to create a HMACSHA256 is ExactTarget. I tried to include CryptoJs in a SSJS. And looked into the documentation of SSJS.

**Question**

Is there anyway to get this done in exactTarget?

Comment: Encrypt what?  Files or field values?  In an email?

Comment: I want to encrypt strings. in SSJS